# Tkinter frames not expanding equally with similar packing arguments

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to build a UI using tkinter that splits the window into 2 sections using 2 frames, however I can't get them to be equal in width.

Rough visualisation of layout:
[image: Rough visualisation of layout]

My original approach was to have 1 frame with side = LEFT and 1 frame with side = RIGHT, and both frames would have fill = BOTH and expand = YES. This method worked fine when the frames were empty, but the left frame became wider than the right when widgets were added to them.

Left frame is red and right frame is blue, behaves as expected:
[image: Left frame is red and right frame is blue, behaves as expected.]

No longer works (same packing):
[image: No longer works (same packing)]

Code used (without menubar):

```py
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
master.geometry("500x500")

lframe = Frame(bg = 'red', relief = "raised", bd = 2)
rframe = Frame(bg = 'blue',relief = "raised", bd = 2)

# Set up for left frame
password_options = Listbox(lframe)
password_options.pack(side = "left", fill = 'both', expand = 1)

password_scrollbar = Scrollbar(lframe)
password_scrollbar.pack(side = 'left', anchor = 'w', fill = 'y', expand = 1)

# Set up for right frame
b = Button(rframe, text = "TEST")
b.pack(expand = 1, fill = 'both')

lframe.pack(side = "left", fill = "both", expand = 1)
rframe.pack(side = "right", fill = "both", expand = 1)
master.mainloop()
```

I thought the frames would still be equal in width after adding widgets, but it seems not. What could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Tk's normal behavior is to size containers based solely on the space needed by their contents.  Making two different containers the same width, regardless of what's in them, is simply not what Tk is designed for, and the `pack` geometry manager doesn't support it.  You *can* do it with `grid`, however - `.columnconfigure()` can be given a `uniform=` option; any two columns where this option has the same value will be forced to the same width.  (Note that using `grid` for the top-level frames doesn't prevent you from using `pack` in the frames themselves.)

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks, using the grid for the frames seems to have done the job. Strange that the uniform option isn't documented anywhere I've looked, but it worked like a charm. I'm not 100% sure how this works, but if you post your comment as an answer can I accept it as is?